# EF: Automatically load related data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Currently when I want to select accounts with related properties, I have to include them manually everytime I select data:

```
public async Task<List<AccountDataModel>> GetAccountsAsync()
{
    return await _dbContext.Accounts.Include(a => a.Settings).ToListAsync();
}

public Task<AccountDataModel> GetAccountByLoginAsync(string login)
{
    return Task.FromResult(_dbContext.Accounts.Include(a => a.Settings).Where(a => a.Login.Equals(login)).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Data models:

```
public class AccountDataModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public SettingsDataModel Settings { get; set; } = new SettingsDataModel();
} 

public class SettingsDataModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public AccountDataModel Account { get; set; }
}
```

Relation setting:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AccountDataModel>(e =>
{
    // Set primary key
    e.HasKey(a => a.Id);

    // Settings one-to-one relationship
    e.HasOne(a => a.Settings)
        .WithOne(s => s.Account)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
        .HasForeignKey<SettingsDataModel>(s => s.Id)
        .IsRequired();
});
```

I was wondering, if this is possible to automatically load related `Settings` property for each `Account` selected?

I'm using the lastest version of EF Core.

Comment: Have you tried [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading)?

Comment: @CodeNotFound Actually I was looking at the same article but I somehow missed that.... Gonna give it a try, looks like this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @CodeNotFound `ADO.NET Entity Framework, the Object-Relational-Mapping (ORM) tools for the .NET Framework. **Add a version specific tag as well, when applicable.**` EF6 and EFCore are different versions so I think it fits in my case.

Comment: Ow :) So comment deleted.

Comment: @CodeNotFound Meanwhile I think you can post the answer regarding Lazy Loading :)